# Can opponents keep Jeskai Infiltrator under their control past the end of their turn if it was manifested?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So recently, when I was vsing a friend, they used [Act of Treason](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Act%20of%20Treason) on my [Jeskai Infiltrator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jeskai%20Infiltrator), then attacked me. I took the damage without blocking, then Jeskai and the top card of their library was exiled, shuffled, and manifested because of the second ability.

Reading other posts on this site, it seems that they would keep control of the manifested cards past the end of their turn, but it was never directly stated. So I just want some clarification on the rules of this card: do they get to keep it?

Comment: Could you clarify who the "we" and "they" are? Is your friend your opponent or your ally in this?

Comment: The "we" was the group I was playing with, and "friend" and "they" refers to my opponents.

Comment: Suggestion might be to change we and us to me and I, due to the possibility of it obfuscating the question, despite the answer being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will keep control of Jeskai Infiltrator. The card was exiled and then returned to the battlefield, so it is considered by the rules a new permanent with no relation to the card that Act of Treason was used on.

> **400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.** There are seven exceptions to this rule:

(none of the exceptions apply here).

Remember that everybody will know which of the face down cards is Jeskai Infiltrator, because who is the owner of a card is always known. There is a ruling in Jeskai Infiltrator that confirms this.

Comment: Thank you Pablo for the feedback. It was good to get this off my chest.

Comment: @Pablo Recommendation to add, although it's not directly necessary to correctly answer the question: When your opponent controls two manifested cards, and one of them is your opponent's, you have to inform them which one of them is theirs, even if you've shuffled them like Jeskai Infiltrator's effect.

Comment: @Waterseas I can't find any rule about that. Could you tell me where have you learned it?

Comment: @Pablo Unfortunately not certain what rule it is based on off-hand, however this is the appropriate ruling on the card: "11/24/2014: A card’s owner is public information at all times. If the two cards you exile are owned by different players (perhaps because you gained control of a Jeskai Infiltrator owned by your opponent), which card is which is no longer hidden from your opponent. That player will know which face-down creature he or she owns."